# Netbeans annotations in generated sources

Tags: java, netbeans, jaxb, annotations

I am using `NetBeans 8.2.`

I have generated some java sources using **JaxB** and **xsd** schema that was provided to me.

(by the way the `xsd` schema is given and should not change)

Now in order to be able to marshal objects into `xml` properly (e.g to have a correct timestamp format) I had to add some annotations to the generated sources  like the following

```
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar timestamp;
```

Everything runs smoothly.

However, the problem is that on clean and build all the generated files are regenerated anew and added annotations are lost.

What can I do, so that either:

1. clean and build will leave generated sources untouched

**or**

2. needed annotations are automatically inserted into generated files after clean and build ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the `jaxb` binding in `Netbeans` creates `JaxBBindings` Directory, in which it puts the binding `xsd` file.

What one needs to do is to edit this `xsd` and add proper (inline) binding customisation. 
Note that in order for the following to compile I had to check `"Use Extension"`  in `"Change JAXB options"` menu (right click on bindings subfolder).

```
<xsd:schema ...
      xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
      xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
      jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
>
...
    <xsd:element name="Timestamp" type="xsd:dateTime">
         <xsd:annotation>
              <xsd:appinfo>
                <xjc:javaType name="javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar" adapter="myadapters.DateTimeAdapter"/>
              </xsd:appinfo>
         </xsd:annotation>
     </xsd:element>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to archive you can do with jax binding customization:

> Customizations to JAXB bindings made by means of an external file
>   containing binding declarations take the general form shown below.

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation = "xs:anyURI">
   <jxb:bindings node = "xs:string">*
      <binding declaration>
   <jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

> - schemaLocation is a URI reference to the remote schema
> - node is an XPath 1.0 expression that identifies the schema node within
>     schemaLocation to which the given binding declaration is associated.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148366

Comment: Thanks for your reply - it was a push in a right direction ;-) So, I am upvoting and  I will post my final solution as a separate answer.